# After login Ncmpcpp shows empty library, have to restart mpd service manually

Tags: mpd

A year ago I found this great combination between `ncmpcpp` and `mpd`. I set my library with `mpd` and the `ncmpcpp` player. I am however facing an issue that is constantly reoccurring - every time I logout or wake my computer up from hibernation (to HDD) `ncmpcpp` appears to have an empty library, list and everything that is `mpd`-related. `mpd` is running (checked for the process and also running `mpd` command returns that the address has already been taken hence the new call is unable to bind to the given address).

So far the solution I have found by experimenting is to simply call

```
$ sudo service mpd stop
```

to stop `mpd` and then restart it by calling

```
$ mpd
```

Has anyone experienced something like this? It's not too much of a fuss but I kind of find it annoying to have to do that on a regular basis.

Comment: When `ncmpcpp` is hanging, does `mpc -h hostname -p port ls` return music directories? Also, any particular reason are you stopping the system service `mpd`, and then starting a user process `mpd`?

Comment: `mpd -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6600 ls` doesn't work since those parameters are not available (I have no `mpc` so I presume you did a typo). Also if start the service with `sudo service mpd start` or restart it with `sudo service mpd restart` the problem doesn't go away. I was just trying out various combinations and starting `mpd` the way I described in my question is the only way it works. I have also updated the question to include that after waking up from hibernation (to HDD) the problem appears too.

Comment: mpc is http://www.musicpd.org/clients/mpc/. Does everything ever work correctly when you start mpd via `sudo service`?

Comment: Thanks for the info and nope, `mpd` works properly only when I start it as a normal user that is no `sudo` involved.

Answer (score 1):

Since mpd is a user service (if you didn’t installed it systemwide for a multi-instance audio server), try this.

First get the status of systemwide mpd.service & socket status by,

```
systemctl status mpd.socket 
systemctl status mpd.service
```

If that is enabled and Active (ie running), U have to stop and disable it,

```
systemctl disable mpd.socket
systemctl stop mpd.socket
```

Then do the same for mpd.service, make sure you stop the socket first to avoid it reactivating the mpd.service agian.

You can use the same status command from the top to make sure everything went as intended!

Now time to enable and start mpd.service for the user,

Use these one by one,

```
systemctl —-user enable mpd.socket 
systemctl —-user enable mpd.service
systemctl —-user start mpd.socket
systemctl —-user start mpd.service
```

Errors you might face,

Permission Denied - Try the same command with "sudo"

user mpd.socket throws some error, might be the systemwide socket still hold it, make sure you enabled both "service & socket" of user and reboot.